# Invalid visualization type: gantt with angular-google-chart

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

I'm working in an **AngularJS** project and I'm trying to add a *Google Gantt chart* with `angular-google-chart` tool, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

**JS CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngRoute',
   'angular.filter',
   'googlechart'
]);

app.value('googleChartApiConfig', {
    version: '1.1',
    optionalSettings: {
      packages: ['gantt'],
      language: 'en'
    }
});


app.controller("chartController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.ganttChart = {
        "type": "gantt",
        "data": {

           "cols": [
                {id: 'Task ID', type: 'string'},
                {id: 'Task Name', type: 'string'},
                {id: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
                {id: 'End Date', type: 'date'},
                {id: 'Duration', type: 'number'},
                {id: 'Percent Complete', type: 'number'},
                {id: 'Dependencies', type: 'string'}
            ], 
            "rows": [
                {c: [
                    {v: 'Research'},
                    {v: 'Find sources'},
                    {v: new Date(2015, 0, 1)},
                    {v: new Date(2015, 0, 5)},
                    {v: null},
                    {v: 100},
                    {v: null}
                ]},
                {c: [
                    {v: 'Write'},
                    {v: 'Write paper'},
                    {v: null},
                    {v: new Date(2015, 0, 9)},
                    {v: daysToMilliseconds(3)},
                    {v: 25},
                    {v: 'Research'}
                ]}
            ]
        }
    };
});


function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
      return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div google-chart chart="ganttChart" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
```

When I run the application instead of showing the chart, *Invalid visualization type: gantt* appears, and the console don't show any error.

I tried this data composition in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7oocLpf/) (example of *Google Gantt Chart* , no `angular-google-chart`tool) and it works fine.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!! And sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the library uses an old version of the chart library. To use the latest one you must change the way the [library is loaded](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs).
This was fixed by *cjeffers* on [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/8427e67798b9a1513aaee28424963aa2f1224d92/ng-google-chart.js).
You can set the value of `useGstaticLoader` to `true` to use the new library loader by default.

Comment: Reference there: http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/providers/agcGstaticLoaderProvider/