# Google chart : Invalid visualization type: gantt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886898/invalid-visualization-type-gantt-with-angular-google-chart) but the problem persists.

I've changed `useGstaticLoader: true` in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/8427e67798b9a1513aaee28424963aa2f1224d92/ng-google-chart.js)

and then in the view i get : `Invalid visualization type: gantt`

Any suggestion is welcome.

**Anyone who Have a good Gantt chart  can he please metion it. Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give much details. If you need/want to use AngularJS, you have angular-gantt as an option https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/.

Or if you want no dependencies and a lightweight library, you could use jsGanttImproved https://github.com/jsGanttImproved/jsgantt-improved

Both are open-source projects.